# Scape webpage but can not find page links

Tags: html, json, selenium, screen-scraping

I am think to scape some data from the following webpage using selenim and beautiful soup. But when inspect the html I could not locate the page number link.

http://quote.eastmoney.com/center/boardlist.html#concept_board

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please show the [Minimum Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you tried?

Comment: I just set up the selenim and installed the chromedirver.

Comment: I just set up the selenim and installed the chromedirver.import os
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_BIN="/usr/local/bin"



browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/Users/Jiong/path/to/chromedriver")
browser.get('http://quote.eastmoney.com/center/boardlist.html#concept_board')
But could not locate the page number at all. I noticed in chrome developer tool source section there is a link to the http://17.push2.eastmoney.com/api/qt/clist/get?cb=jQuery1124009684726272828859_1642469099402&pn=1&pz=20&po=1&np=1&ut=bd1d9ddb04089700cf9c27f6f74262.....

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of things here:

You are trying to get a url, but didn't provide the proper sytanx. There is no http protocol provided (see below code)
I am not sure if you are trying to locate just a page number, or trying to click on the next page and so on, you click on `Go` button.
Here is the code until what you have provided.

```
driver.get("https://quote.eastmoney.com/center/boardlist.html#concept_board")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'paginte_go')).click()   # to locate to 'Go' button and click on it to go to next page
```

I am not sure why code format is not working today. I am sorry for this text-ish style of format

Comment: Thanks I found the following works.  Not sure there is anything one can do to make it more efficient. Another question is that if it is possible to get the javascript and change the parameter page size so only need query once instead of 18.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_all=pd.DataFrame() 
for j in range(1,18):
 browser.get('http://quote.eastmoney.com/center/boardlist.html#concept_board')
mtable = browser.find_element_by_id('table_wrapper-table')
content = browser.find_element_by_class_name('paginate_input')
button_go = browser.find_element_by_link_text('GO')
content.clear()
content.send_keys(str(j))
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_link_text('GO').click()
time.sleep(5)
mtable = browser.find_element_by_id('table_wrapper-table')
for row in mtable.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
    i=0
    for cell in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
        i+=1
        if i==2:
            print(cell.text, cell.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")[0].get_attribute("href"))
```